# Check if Music is playing in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm attempting to build a chrome extension.

How can I check if headphones are plugged in and/or if music is playing in the system (or, if that's not possible, at least the browser)? Is there a way to do that in a javascript API callback?

I'm new to this extension world and appreciate the help. Cheers.

For example, I've looked into using getAllFrames with the tab id, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't hook into the system like that natively with Javascript API.  However, if you're looking to determine if audio or video is playing in chrome, a simple idea is to inject a script into each page and have it report to your background.js file whether it has found any <audio> <video> or <object>(??) tags, and their state.  But that's kind of hodge-podge of an answer...

Comment: @AaronSaray I think that should be satisfactory, but I'm not sure how I'd inject a script to report to my background file given those tags. Can you give a tutorial or some sample code? I'll add in what I've tried so far.

Comment: Well, if you're familiar with Chrome extension, you know that background.js is available and ran in each chrome tab's context.  If you want, you can also launch other js files (for example, if you wanted to run something only on dev-tools launch, you could do that).  Anyway, it would be as simple as putting a document.querySelectorAll() command for all the possible audio players - and then check to see if their attribute playing is going.  If you want this in an answer form, let me know - and I'll write one up as the answer (for hopefully an accepted answer checkmark? ;) )